# Cakephp 3 paginator sort fields with translate behavior i18n

Tags: sorting, internationalization, cakephp-3.0, paginator

I have a `Posts` table with `Translate` behavior and I want to sort it by title on the table at index view. I can't sort by the fields that are translated because the field's don't actually exist on the database. They exist on the `i18n` table.

This, as I explained above, doesn't work:

```
$this->Paginator->sort('title');
$this->Paginator->sort('Posts_title_translation.content');
```

So, what I should do? What am I missing?

Many Thanks!

Comment: "_doesn't work_" is not a proper problem description, please always be specific about what exactly happens (like for example the fact that no `ORDER BY` clause will be generated), even if the problem seems obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second variant should work once the field is being whitelisted, which is generally necessary for associations to be used for sorting:

```
$this->paginate = [
    // ...
    'sortWhitelist' => [
        'Posts_title_translation.content',
        // ...
    ]
];
```

Note that with the whitelist in place, you will have to add all other fields of your `Posts` table that need to be used for sorting too!

See also **[Cookbook > ... Components > Pagination > Control which Fields Used for Ordering](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/pagination.html#control-which-fields-used-for-ordering)**